# True or false? If $f(X)$ is the image of $f$ on the set $X$ then $f\colon X \to f(X)$ must be surjective

Tags: functions

Title. It seems obvious to prove because if I suppose $y \in f(X)$ then by definition there is a $x \in X$ so that $f(x)  = y$. But I am slightly uncertain.

Comment: This is indeed true by the definition of $f(X)$.

Comment: What's with all the negative votes? It's a beginner's question, sure, but it's an honest question that warrants an answer.

Comment: It should't be down voted, he has formatted properly unlike many other new contributors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a map $f$ is surjective if the image of the map is equal to the codomain. By restricting the codomain to the image, we are forcing this property to occur, and thus also making $f$ surjective.